# Using onclick with a partial HTML button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When using onclick in the markup without using a partial HTML element, the onclick function works, but when using the exact same markup in a partial, it does not execute the onclick function

Question: Is there a way to get the onclick function to work using a partial HTML element, or do you have to write the markup normally?

This is my partial Submit button:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button1" />
```

This is where is my JavaScript Confirm function:

```
    function Confirm(message, okayMessage, cancelMessage) {
        var result = confirm(message);
        if (result == true) {
            alert(okayMessage);
        } else {
            alert(cancelMessage);
        }
    }
```

This is where I call the onclick function where I use the partial button and Confirm script:

```
    <partial name="_SubmitButton" onclick="Confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this skill?', 'Skill has been deleted', 'Skill was NOT deleted')" />
```

This is the link at the bottom of my markup to the stylesheet (It definitely works):

```
    @section Scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/Popups.js"></script>
    }
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: It works when i do not use the button as a partial, but when i use the exact same markup but in a partial, it doesn't work. I was wondering if there is a way

Answer (score 1):

Hi its all because of our old friend DOM.

Say when you have a partial page like this it will be loaded with the main page and will be binded with the DOM only after that your partial view would be loaded.

This all happens because your partial button is not binded with DOM. 
Just do one thing open your console in browser and try to `getElementByName('_SubmitButton');`

You will get undefined the best option would be place your `js` inside partial page itself then i guess it should work

and also if you put it inside

```
 @section Scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/Popups.js"></script>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial tag helper is for server side code execution, so it does not recognize Confirm function from frontend.